# Tricky structure Pointer iterating without giving dump

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure

Tricky structure Pointer iterating without giving dump

Structure Pointer isn't giving Dump

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct 
{
 int k;       

}struct1;        

typedef struct 
{
  int i;
  char *ptr;     
  int len;     
  struct1 otherinstance;
}struct2;

int func(struct2 *instance,int y)
{
    int res = 0,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
    instance[i].otherinstance.k = 10;
    printf("Data = %d\n",instance[i].otherinstance.k);
    }    
    return res;        
}


int main()
{
 int x =3;   
 struct2 *instance1 = (struct2*)malloc(sizeof(struct2));
 func(instance1,3);  
 cin.get();  
 return 0;   
}

/*
Output:
Data = 10       
Data = 10
Data = 10       
*/
```

Please analyse the above code. I have a function name "func" which accepts the pointer to structure. 
Inside the function "func" i am iterating through the array of structure : "SHOULD GIVE DUMP".

Tools : dev c++ windows

Comment: Cryptic question is cryptic... **What is your question, exactly?**

Comment: 1. When i am passing structure pointer . why its not giving warning/error while compile time that i am using array of structure pointer.

Comment: 1. I understand the undefined behaviour. but i have allocated memory for only one instance how the other instance is referring members inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

You mean you know sizeof(instance1) should be n * sizeof(*instance1) and why it doesnt crash in func? 
Thats called undefined behaviour, it can work because the memory returned from malloc is valid memory and you can access it inside func. Try running it in release build and optimizations on etc and see when it starts to crash.

Comment: Yeah .. it iterates for 700+-40 times and gives dump

Comment: how do i stop such types mistakes ? or add validation ?

Comment: you dont, it comes with experience. In C lots of burden is put on the programmer theres no safety net

Comment: @PragRao: To detect memory management errors you might like to test your program by running it under a tool like Valgrind: http://valgrind.org

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behaviour. And use `sizeof(struct2)` in `malloc` It would crash in most compilers.